# How do I subscribe to @computed object in mobx?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I want to subscribe to a computed property that returns a simple object.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-noether-g8g0x

I made a simple example of my situation to show exactly what the problem is:

```js
const zeroSize = {
    width: 0,
    height: 0
};

class Item {
    @observable size = zeroSize;
}

class Collection {
    @observable childrens: Item[] = [];

    @computed get size() {
        return this.childrens.length > 0 && this.childrens[0] ? this.childrens[0].size : zeroSize;
    }

    constructor() {
        reaction(() => this.size, size => {
            // Expected { width: 0, height: 1000 }
            // Actual { width: 0, height: 0 }
            console.log('-----size=', toJS(size));
        });
    }
}

const item1 = new Item;
const collection1 = new Collection;
collection1.childrens.push(item1);
item1.size.height = 1000;
```

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/2176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are listening for the wrong change.

Because you are listening for changes to size, the height will trigger a change:

```
const item1 = new Item; // size === 0
const collection1 = new Collection; // size === 0
collection1.childrens.push(item1); // size === 1 (triggers reaction)
item1.size.height = 1000; // size === 1 (doesn't trigger reaction)
```

If you want to listen to any and all changes that are the result of `childrens` changing, then that is what you need to be listening to changes for.

```
reaction(
  () => toJS(this.childrens),
  size => {
    // Expected { width: 0, height: 1000 }
    // Actual { width: 0, height: 0 }
    console.log("-----size=", toJS(this.size));
  }
);
```

By listening to `toJS(this.childrens)`, you can subscribe to when the length of childrens changes, but also when a property of an element of childrens changes.

If you only want to listen to when new children are added or removed, then listening to `size` make sense. If you want to listen to when children are added, removed or modified, then you need to change what you are listening to.

Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/white-hill-fntxt

And the relevant console logs:

```
-----size= Object {width: 0, height: 0}
-----size= Object {width: 0, height: 1000}
```

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob yes i think you may need to